# How to solve "No SLF4J providers were found" when the "slf4j-api" and "slf4j-simple" are already imported?

Tags: java, gradle, slf4j

I am using Guice in a gradle project. When running the main method, I got the following error:

```
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
```

I did some research and added two dependencies in the `dependencies` section of the `build.gradle` file as shown below:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '2.0.0-alpha1'
    testImplementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: '2.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

But the error is still there...

Do I need to bind the SLF4J provider with something via Guice?

My `main` method is very simple, so as the `AbstractModule` class for Guice, as shown below (not sure if they are relevant):

```
public class Restful {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new ApplicationModule());
    }
}
```

and

```
public class ApplicationModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(UserDao.class).toInstance(new UserDao());
    }
}
```

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You added `slf4j-simple` only in test scope, you want it also in runtime scope.

I.e. change `testImplementation` to `implementation` in your build definition.

---

Note that `slf4j-simple` as the name suggests is a minimal implementation of SLF4J API, you might want to use a more customizable one for production code like logback, log4j2...

Comment: How to do that? Can you add that for future reference please?

Comment: @theprogrammer added

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick reply. :)

Comment: Hmm, why is mvnrepository.com suggesting testImplementation rather than implementation? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple/2.0.6

Comment: @szx because usually you use it for tests only and use a more configurable implementation for production like logback.